# Need help creating a user defined date and then use a convertdays method to return in one long integer

Tags: java, date

Basically I need to write a program that has the user input the date in one input in the form mm dd yyyy using a space between each like shown. Then I have to save the month, day and year parts in 3 separate variables. Once that's done I have to send those to a convertdays method that will return the date in the form of of one long integer using: the long year will be sum of the year multiplied by 10000, the month multiplied by 100, and just the day regular. The rest I can do myself but these I'm stuck on. Really I know it should only be two basic steps but I'm a novice to java and programming in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank youuu!

I'm an extreme novice and can hardly understand java let alone write it. I'm sorry.

This is what I have so far:

```
int month, day, year, date;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a valid date below putting a space between the month, day, and year");
        SimpleDateFormat format = 
            new SimpleDateFormat("
```

Also the last part of the program calculates the leap year which should be working now. Feel free to critique it if it's wrong though:

```
{
            println("This program calculates leap year.");
            int year = readInt("Enter the year: ");

            boolean isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));

            if (isLeapYear)
        {
            println(year + " is a leap year.");
        }
            else
            println(year + " is not a leap year.");
        }
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: So much text, so little question.

Comment: Your starting points are `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, and `Calendar`. All are standard Java library classes.

Comment: Alright, I edited the original post

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat#parse method to convert the date text used entered using format "MM dd yyyy".

Like,

```
    // User Entered date text
    String dateText = "11 18 2013 ";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy");

    Date date = format.parse(dateText); 
    //Print long value of date
        System.out.println(date.getTime());


    // Month--> 11 , Date--> 18 , Year---> 2013 
    System.out.printf("Month--> %d , Date--> %d , Year---> %d \n",
            date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate(), date.getYear() + 1900);

    // Print long value of date
    System.out.println(date.getTime());
```